# Query ActiveRecord for first object with match to partial attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a scaffold for a `user` model which has a `name` attribute. Index looks like this:
[image]

I want to do a query that finds only the *first* record whose name begins with the two letters of: "Mr".  So for above it would return the record with the name "Mr Bar".

I know it might look something close to this:

```
User.find_by(name: name[0].concat(name[1]) == "Mr") # doesn't work
```

Comment: I upvoted you back. I think you have a good question, and I edited the title.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a `where` method to obtain Users whose name starts from "Mr" and first to obtain the first result of the query

```
User.where("name like ?", "Mr%").first
```

Comment: Just made an edit to the answer. I just removed the '%' symbol before "Mr" which ensures that names starting with "Mr" are picked